# Center logo in middle of navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I am looking to display my logo in the middle of my centered top navigational menu. As it stands right now, I have the logo sitting on top of it. Would it be easiest if I split the menu items into different containers and then used margins and padding to accomplish this? Or is there a more efficient way?

Here is a JS Fiddle showing my current scenario. [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f29QS/2/)

Here is my current CSS:

```
.container {
width:960px;
margin:0 auto;
}
header, main{
    display: block;
}
.container-narrow {
margin:0 auto;
width:640px;
}

h1.logo {
width:300px;
margin:0 auto;
text-indent:100%;
overflow:hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
}

body h1 {
background:url(http://placehold.it/300x80) no-repeat;
height:80px;
}

body section.menu,body header.top-section {
background:url(../img/menu-bg.png) repeat;
padding:60px 0;
}

body header.top-section {
padding:40px 0;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
z-index:50;
}

#menu_container {
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-family:'intro_regular', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0;
    /*margin-top: -70px;
    position: relative;*/
    z-index: 20;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#menu_container .nav ul { list-style: none; overflow: auto; }
#menu_container .nav li { float: left; padding: 0.4em 0.8em; font-size: 0.9em; line-height: 1em; cursor: pointer; }
#menu_container .nav li a { text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; }
#menu_container .nav li:hover a,
#menu_container .nav li.active a { color: #fff !important; }
#menu_container .nav li.contact_screen:hover a,
#menu_container .nav li.contact_screen.active a { color: white !important; }
#menu_container .nav li a { color: #000000; }
#menu_container .nav li a { transition: all 400ms; -webkit-transition: all 400ms; }
#menu_links { display: inline-block; }
#menu_button { display: none; color: white; cursor: pointer; text-align: right; padding: 0 0.8em; }
#menu_button i { font-size: 1.3em; margin-right: -0.3em; color:#bc9321;}
#menu_links li:first-child {}
```

Comment: If I were you I'd use an nth-child selector to apply an even padding to the two middle `li` elements (maybe 160px to the right of the left `li` and 160px to the left of the right `li`, assuming they're even).

Comment: I was marking up something very similar when I figured, "God, someone's got to have written something about this before." [Here you go.](http://stanislav.it/how-to-center-a-logo-in-unordered-list-navigation-using-css3-nth-child-selector/)

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work in IE8 as is.

Comment: Didn't catch that as a prerequisite. Fortunately, if IE8 continues its trend [it will be at ~1.5% share by the time this year's out](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp). I guess a JavaScript solution or a little hackery would work if IE8 is a must.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this very scenario recently. I got it working by positioning the logo absolutely, then using `:nth-child` selectors to target the elements on either side of the logo and add margins to make room.

[Here's the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QdF6W/)

`:nth-child` is great, but you might want a fallback set of styles for [older browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) .

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered CSS3 display: flex?

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

The issue I run into with this setup is that when you want to switch to smaller screens - this wouldnt work as well as your logo is still placed in the middle instead of allowing them stack block...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You could stick your logo class as an li in the middle.

```
        <div id="menu_links" class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="home_link"><a href="#splash_wrapper">Home</a></li>
                <li class="menus_link"><a href="#menus_wrapper">Menus</a></li>  
<li class="logo">Restauraunt</li
                <li class="contact_link"><a href="#contact_wrapper">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="reservations_link"><a href="#reservations_wrapper">Reservations</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Then change h1.logo to li.logo.

Comment: So is using a div for a nav instead of using the nav tag.

Comment: No disagreements there.